# sp-npos-elections compile error in polkadot-v0.9.24

Tags: bug

When I build subtrate node template with below libary, this issue is happened. How to fix that. I use rust: 1.64.0 and nightly-2022-07-14 (stable now).
Polkadot version: 0.9.24

[image]

Comment: Try adding use sp_std::prelude::*;

Answer (score 1):

This error usually happens when you forget to add the `std` feature to the crate you imported.

So try updating your cargo file to:

```rust
[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    ....
    "sp-npos-elections/std",
    ....
]
```

And make sure the crate is imported with `default-features = false`

Comment: This is still happen when I add it cargo.toml, anything help to fix this?

Comment: You need to provide more details then. For example concrete, minimal steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the compiler is asking for `sp_std::vec`

Try adding the following to your .toml file:

```
sp-std = { version = "4.0.0-dev", default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", branch = "polkadot-v0.9.24" }
```

```
[features]
default = ["std"]
std = [
    ....
    "sp-std/std",
    ....
]
```

Comment: This is still happen when I add it cargo.toml, anything help to fix this?